# What are the specific names for the various username formats in Windows?

Tags: windows, active-directory, syntax, username

When windows users are prompted to enter their username, they can usually specify it in a variety of formats:

- username
- username@activedirectorydomain.example
- addomain\username

What are the technical terms for each of these? I'd like to know for future reference in case I need a specific format entered.

Comment: A given login either will be part of a domain, and in order to log into an account on the domain you have to specify the domain/network or will simply be a local user account to that specific device.  There are no other types of Windows accounts besides a domain account and a local account.  2 of your examples are domain account one is a local account.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Is this not a legitimate question?  I checked for duplicates prior to asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The info you seek is available from MS here: [User Name Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx).

There are actually only two types of user names, "User Principal Name" and "Down-Level Logon Name"

**User Principal Name:**

> User principal name (UPN) format is used to specify an Internet-style name, such as *UserName@Example.Microsoft.com*.

**Down-Level Logon Name:**

> The down-level logon name format is used to specify a domain and a user account in that domain, for example, *DOMAIN\UserName*.

The one where you don't enter a domain name is just using one of these, but it's appending the default domain (or the computer) name for you.